# How do I read value of variable defined in FileReader.onloadend inside XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange callback functin?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, filereader

In the code below, I need read the value of variable `ext` (defined inside the function `reader.onloadend`) in the function `xhr.onreadystatechange`. Right now is returning `undefined`. Any ideas how to fix that?

```
function file_upload(file_input) {
  var name = file_input.dataset.target;
  var url = file_input.dataset.url;
  var path = file_input.dataset.path;
  var ext;

  for(var i = 0; i<file_input.files.length; i++) {
    var file = file_input.files[i];
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var id = xhr.responseText;
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            input.setAttribute("name", name);
            input.setAttribute("value", id);
            document.getElementById("btn_uload_"+name+"_"+ext).append(input);
            document.getElementById("empty_file").style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById("single_file_"+ext).style.display = 'block';
        }
    };
    var reader  = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      var bytes = reader.result;
      var ext = file.name.split(".").pop();
      var formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('bytes', bytes);
      formData.append('type', ext);
      xhr.send(formData);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just create `ext` at the top of the loop, it isnt dependent on anything in the filrereader event and use `let` instead of `var` so it becomes block scoped to the loop

Comment: I already do that, `ext` is created on the top of the function (fourth line on the code above).

Comment: no you need to do `let ext = ...` at the top of your loop. defining it at the top of your function is not the same thing

Comment: Ok, I try that (I use `let ext=''` instead `var ext` on the top of the function), but still got undefined when it's used in the line `document.getElementById("btn_uload_"+name+"_"+ext).append(input)`

Comment: I think somehow the block inside `xhr.onreadystatechange` is being called before the one inside `reader.onloadend`? I could be wrong. Is it could be some synchronization issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `var ext =...` from the reader callback that is only making a local variable for that function (it isnt setting the external one. Even if you remove the `var` keyword so that it starts setting the external `ext` variable you will end up hitting an issue discussed at [this q&a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Move your assignment to the top of the loop(not the top of the function). And use `let` instead of `var` that way it is block scoped and wont run into the previously mentioned issue

```
for(var i = 0; i<file_input.files.length; i++) {
    var file = file_input.files[i];
    let ext = file.name.split('.').pop();
```